# PHP cURL response error when comparing in if statement

Tags: php, http, curl, comparison, response

Ok, this literally makes no sense...
I am using this function to call an API

```
function get_web_page($url) {
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",     // handle compressed
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "API", // name of client
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   // set referrer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    // time-out on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,    // time-out on response
    ); 

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $content  = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;
}
```

Which works find if i do something like this

```
$exampleResponse = get_web_page("https://example.com/index.php?example=1");
echo $exampleResponse;
```

But what makes absolutely no sense (to me) is that trying to compare the response in a if statement DOES NOT WORK! Here is an example (assume the API response is `"example"`)

```
$exampleResponse = get_web_page("https://example.com/index.php?example=1");
if($exampleResponse == "example")
{
    echo "ok";
}
```

This will not work and `ok` will NOT be echoed even though the API responded with `"example"`. This is very confusing to me, if anyone has any idea why this may be occurring please let me know - thanks for your time.

Comment: Check what **exactly** you have there: `var_dump($exampleResponse);`

Comment: What about `if (trim($exampleResponse) == "example") { ... }`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis wow, that worked, thanks!

Comment: @geegeeWap Always check for extra whitespace when debugging issues like this.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Will do from now on! Thanks again